# Assign civi group by membership subscription?

Tags: civimember, joomla, groups

Is it possible to automactically assign contacts to a civi-group by membership subscription?

Then when membership expired or remove contacts will be remove from that group?

We need it for our joomla website so we can assign user to a joomla group by this plugin here https://github.com/lcdservices/CiviCRM-Group-Sync (we tried using civi-authenticate plugin for joomla, but thats dont work properly)

We are struggling, so will appreciate any help.

Thanks
Julash

Comment: Whats stopping you using smart groups? They should refresh automatically based on the search criteria used?

Answer (score 1):

in principe you could do that with the CiviRules extension (which you can get from https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules). With this extension you can set up a trigger 'new membership' (or possibly a change of membership status?), add a condition for the specific membership type if required and add an action to automatically add the contact to a group.
There is a cookbook on CiviRules on the Wiki documentation: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+Cookbook